# Convert html to wordpress & provide link to menu inside panel

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have an HTML template which I am trying to convert into PHP for WordPress.

The homepage has been converted and is shown properly. Next, the menu in navbar is about, the page that needs to be converted in PHP.

I have just added `get_header()` at the top and `get_footer()` below. In between these two I have added the HTML content for my entire page.

Then I tried to provide the link for the menu that I created, but the content of about page is not visible.

Do I need to add any other line for that page apart from `get_header` and `get_footer`? Or is something wrong with the link?

Comment: please read about this https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: Nothing good on this link I have read. I need to provide link to php pages in wordpress custom menu

Comment: i am not getting your point. i can help you if explain me betterly

Comment: Ok I have html template that has menu home , about, contact. Home is html page which I have converted into home.php(index) for wordpress. Now I need to create php page for about, which initially is in html and content of this about page should be visible on site. Which is not right now. I have used get_header() then html content and then get_footer. then provided link of this php page in menu of admin panel. but nothing visible except header and footer

Comment: No the 2nd page i.e. about . index has already been done

Comment: about.php is file name

Comment: Are you saying the menu in the navbar needs to be converted into PHP or the page itself does - "Next, the menu in navbar is about the page that needs to be converted in PHP."?

Comment: page initially in html needs to be converted into php and then in menu section of dashboard its menu link is supposed to be given. So I don't know what is wrong with th page it is not displaying anything except footer and header but index i.e. home page works fine. About page I don't know whether I have to add anything else along with get_header and get_footer(). or something wrong with menu that content of about.php is not shown in wordpress. Either page conversion is lacking something

Comment: Sajid I can't your code anywhere

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly I can't understand what your are trying to say. I think you want to create a page that will show your about menu content.

So in your theme directory create a page name page.php and use get_header(); in first and below get_footer and where you want to show page content write the_content();. like this

```
<?php 
get_header(); ?>

<div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

after that follow the url of @ Sajid Anwar. because for dynamic data you have to create pages(home,about etc) from wordpress dashboard and in menu section add these pages as navigation menu to menu.

Comment: In my about .php,    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
In this content has to be placed after <?php content(); ?> or before <?php content()?>

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying? why you want to create about.php? if your about page structure is same like others please use only page.php and this page.php will show content of your every menu item content. not require to create any other page for every menu item like about.php , if all of pages has same structure design

Comment: You are getting my point in the right way as your answer relates my solution. Every page has different content but header and footer is same. So do I need to create separate php files for thaem as there is just one page.php in wordpress file. And sir the code which you have mentioned above, the content has to be placed above content() function or below content() function inside div

Comment: replace all your code with my prev code.again- if your every page design is same not content then do not create another php page. and if your every page design is different not content(my be same or different) then create php file. suppose you have about and service page and these two pages design is same and content may not be same just put your html structure in page.php file and in the html file where you want to show page content just use the_content(); function. AND if about and service pages design is different then you have to use "template page" for every page in different php pages.

Comment: design is also a part of content sir its different. OK so for about and contact I have to use template.php for every page? I am not getting exactly what you mean but I am trying to read on all that you said. I will get it done thanx

Comment: for about create a page name about.php and for contact contact.php. in php file top use <?php /* Template Name:about */ ?> for about and for contact <?php /* Template Name:contact*/ ?>.after that line use my prev code. now when you create page from dashboard in right side you can see a dropdown of template now choose and save -> run. Thats all